# The execution of the same code in the main method and JUnit is inconsistent

Tags: java, junit

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");
         s1.intern();
         String s2 = "11";
         System.out.println(s1 == s2); // This result is true.
    }
@Test
    public void test2(){
        String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");
        s1.intern();
        String s2 = "11";
        System.out.println(s1 == s2); // This result is false.
    }
```

1.Why is the execution result of my code in the main method different from that in the JUnit unit test

Comment: Java8 and Junit5

Comment: Can you show the entire classes and how do you run each ? I tried, and they are both `true` on my side too. I assume you don't define any `String` with the value `11` before.

Comment: I run JUnit in idea, not from the main function
`
@Test

public void test(){

String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");

s1.intern();

String s2 = "11";

System.out. println(s1 == s2);

}`

Comment: You can run it, and the result is false, but if you run it in main, the result is true

Answer (score -1):

Since the returned instance of `intern()` is being ignored, the code will behave differently depending if the `"11"` string was already interned or not.

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()) of the `intern()` method:

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

In other words, calling `s1.intern()`  when the string is not yet interned, would return the same instance, that is, the instance of `s1` will be the interned instance and so `s1 == "11"` results in `true`. Otherwise, if `"11"` was already added to the pool¹, `s1.intern()` will return the instance that is already in the pool and not changed the reference stored in `s1`; so `s1 == "11"` must return `false`.

The *correct* way to use the `intern()` method is to use the returned instance:

```
s1 = s1.intern();
```

This guarantees that `s1` is always the instance from the string pool.

---

**¹**  A string will be added to the pool by any previous call of `intern()` on a string with he same content or anywhere, including any library or standard classes, the `"11"` literal is used.

---

---

Comparing what can happen if the string is or not already in the pool.
`@100` means a pointer to an instance, the number (`100`) being a fictive ID (or address) of that instance.

`"11"` not yet in the pool:

```
String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");  // s1=@100
// the literal "1" is in the pool, but the resulting "11" is a new instance, not in/from the pool

s1.intern();  // s1=@100; returns @100
// "11" is not in the pool, so the instance (@100) is added to the pool and returned

String s2 = "11";  // s2=@100
// since there is already a "11" (@100) in the pool, it is used for the literal

System.out.println(s1 == s2);  // true since @100 == @100
```

---

`"11" // @100` already in the pool, maybe the literal was used before:

```
 // somewhere else, already executed (main, standard java classes, junit, ...)
var x = "11";
// or
System.out.println("11");
// now "11" is in the string pool

...

String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");  // s1=@101
// the literal "1" is in the pool, but the resulting "11" is a new instance, not from the pool

s1.intern();  // s1=@101; returns @100 (the value from the pool)
// "11" is in the pool, so the instance (@101) is NOT added to the pool and the pool instance @100 returned
// s1 is not changed and still contains @101, since the return value was not assigned to it

String s2 = "11";  // s2=@100
// since there is already a "11" (@100) in the pool, it is used for the literal

System.out.println(s1 == s2);  // false since @101 == @100
```

Comment: I think s1 originally points to the instance in the heap (at this time, there is no "11" in the string constant pool).
After s1. intern(), s1 should point to the data "11" in the string constant pool.
When s2 is declared, because there is already "11" in the string constant pool,
s2 directly points to the existing "11" in the string constant pool. 
At this time, s1 is equal to s2

Comment: I know what you mean, but I can't understand why the two programs are the same, but the results are different, and they are irrelevant

Comment: I saw this example on the Internet. I was curious and tried it. I didn't understand why the conclusion was different. He didn't use s1 = s1. Intern();

Comment: To make it clearer, why does test4 return false and test5 return true

Comment: for example
```
@Test
    public void test4(){
        String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");
        s1.intern();
        String s2 = "11";
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }
    @Test
    public void test5(){
        String s1 = new String("1") + new String("3");
        s1.intern();
        String s2 = "13";
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }
```

Comment: the result of test4 is false，and the result of test5 is true

Comment: The difference between test4 and test5 lies in the different strings, which leads to different results

For example, the main method at the beginning ,after s1. intern(), in the main method, the memory address pointed to by the reference of s1 is automatically changed (re pointed to the constant pool), but there is no re pointing in JUnit, such as test4 (and I found that 10, 11 and 12 in JUnit are special cases, which will cause s1. Intern() not to re point the reference of s1 to the constant pool)

Comment: I mean, if one of the tests is executed separately, the results of both tests will be true

Comment: Sorry, I should mean string pool

Comment: I have seen your example and understand it
I run JUnit in idea, not from the main function

Comment: `
@Test 
public void test(){ 
 String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1"); 
 s1.intern(); 
 String s2 = "11"; 
 System.out. println(s1 == s2); 
}
`

Comment: You can run it, and the result is false, but if you run it in main, the result is true

Comment: I saw your example. You misunderstood me. I meant to use JUnit unit test execution, not in the main method

Comment: Can you give me an email address? I'll record a demo video for you

Comment: sorry, SURE I will not give the email address, much less will I post it here! I have not registered to stay anonymous!!! And I do not need a video - I am pretty sure you do not understand that the only difference is that the literal can already be in the pool or not (as demonstrated on IDEone) - again, there is nothing special about JUnit, but that the string literal was used before. BTW "not in the main method" -> does not match the code you posted in question **AND** using that code I get `true` no matter if running the `main` or using `JUnit`; and that was already commented by other users

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help.

I didn't write the main method locally, and the result returned by the unit test is false

Comment: see running main: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeWEC.png || and running with JUnit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P91PN.png || maybe you should have added a [mre] in the question  (I'll repeat again - if the literal was used before (or the string was interned before), it will be in the pool and you will get `false` - as I already demonstrated - no matter if using JUnit, some IDE, whatever, ... - maybe `"11"` is being in some other test or setup code) || in short (again) `intern()` is not being used as meant to be used, that is, returned value is being ignored